# 403 with django's class based view

Tags: python, django, post, django-class-based-views, http-status-code-405

So this is a simple view that I have written.

```
class PostTestView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print request.POST
        return HttpResponse("Hello there")
```

my `urls.py` has this line for the above view :

```
url(r'^test/create$',PostTestView.as_view(), name='app.views.create_test')
```

But I get an `405 Http error` when I try to hit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/test/create`

This apparently means that my method `post` is not in the defined methods list . But  I have defined it as above in my view.
What could possibly be wrong here ? I am clueless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try defining the get method.

The "post" method is commonly used in forms, but when you just point your browser to an url the used method is "get"

Comment: Actually, try avoiding overriding `post` and `get` directly, unless you know exactly what you're doing. Instead, use the generic CBVs as a starting point, picking one based on what you're trying to do with your view.

Comment: This is a class-based view (CBV). If you take a look at django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/ override get and post method are the documented way to do things. I guess you are referrening to class-based generic views, and that is a good point, use class-based generic views if you can.

Comment: You are correct, I was talking about generic CBVs. However, unlike function-based views it's highly recommended to try finding an appropriate generic CBV before digging deeper, as you are almost certain to find one. Which is why I made a comment to your answer (which is not incorrect) instead of writing another answer.

Comment: Try FormView or LoginView (from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView).  You'll get the template that you can see with the GET request and then try POST-ing the form with a submit button.